# Custom function for Google Spreadsheet always return the same result

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, google-drive-api

I am trying to build a simple script to work with a Google Spreadsheet that looks like this:

[image]

It shows me which of my clients use which modules of each layer. Each client may use how many modules he wants to.

What I need to do is count how many clients have all the modules installed (or the three layers, it's the same).

I've tried to do this using the built-in functions but have not succeed.

Now I'm trying to do my own function, that looks like this:

```
function countTotalModByClient(values) {

var quantMod=0;
var quantClient=0;

for (var i=0; i<values.length; i++) {
  for(var j=0; j<values.length; j++) {
    if(values[i][j]=="X") {
      quantMod++;
    }
  }

  if(quantMod==15) { // total number of modules
    quantClient++;
  }

  quantMod=0;
}

  return quantClient;
}
```

But it always return the same result: 0.

At my sheet, I'm calling the function like this: `=countTotalModByClient(B3:P6)`

P.S.: Sorry about the magic number in the code, I´ll fix this. =)

Comment: I'm not familiar with Google SpreadSheets, but `countTotalModByClient(B3:P6)` looks invalid JavaScript to me.

Comment: @Teemu Thats the way how functions are called in Google Spreadsheets, for example: `=SUM(A1:A10)`.

Comment: Sorry, my bad, you're calling the function within a formula, not directly from JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be possible with a standard formula (although maybe a little complex).

```
=countif(ArrayFormula(MMULT(--(B3:P6="X"), transpose(column(B3:P2)^0))), 15)
```

should return the number of clients with a count of 15 in their row..
Can you check if that works ?

Or if you prefer a custom function, give this a try:

```
function countTotalModByClient(values) {
var quantClient = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    if (values[i].countItem("X") === 15) quantClient += 1;
}
return quantClient;
}

Array.prototype.countItem = function (item) {
var counts = {};
for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
    var num = this[i];
    counts[num] = counts[num] ? counts[num] + 1 : 1;
}
return counts[item] || 0;
}
```

[Example spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1cT_qw4a8SrVlPGvsH3FWsTmvus4nyuT5T_SKgTVWm-U/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Didn't work, @JPV! The formula has an error and the code still returning 0.

Comment: What's your locale ? Maybe your locale uses semi colons instead of comma's as argument separators ? Just tried both myself and I got it working..

Comment: You were right! I changed the commas by semicolons and the error was gone! Now I need to reorganize the formula to my sheet.

Comment: I tried to understand this formula to reapply it to my sheet, but I it's too much for me... I pasted my entire sheet in the document linked above on your first answer. It would be great if you could help me again. @JPV

Comment: Hi mvalencaa, I added the formulas in the sheet you shared.